# How to create public NSUInteger 2d-array property

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I have this:

```
    @implementation BoardModel
    {
        NSUInteger _board[5][5];
    }
```

I am able to set and get its information in my BoardModel.m file, but I need to access that information in my GameViewController.m file.  Here's what I tried:

```
    @property (nonatomic) NSUInteger board[5][5];
```

I received the error message: 'Property cannot have array or function type NSUInteger *[5][5].'

So, I definitely need to access that information from the BoardModel.m file, and I would like to do it WITHOUT having a setter function in my GameViewController.m file.

Comment: As the error states, you can't create an Objective-C property with C-array types. You have no choice but to write setter/getter methods passing in row/col indexes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mix C arrays with Objective-C classes, this work up to some extent, which does not include being able to use them as properties. You have multiple different solutions to the problem, some of them are:

- use `NSArray` together with `NSNumber` and do everything Objective-C style
- wrap the array inside a `struct` so that you can then access the field correctly through the `struct`.

Something like:

```
typedef struct
{
  NSUInteger data[5][5];
} board;

@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
  board _board;
}

@property(readonly,nonatomic) board* board;

@end

@implementation MyClass

-(board*) board
{
  return &_board;
}

@end
```

Then you'll need to pass through the `struct` to access data, eg: `object.board->data[i][j]`.

Comment: Is there any way to assign that data to 'object'?  Like, alloc-init 'object' in GameViewController.m then build a permanent bridge to that data?

Comment: Actually, rather, am I able then to use the property to access the information in my GameViewController.m?

Answer (score 0):

A property in Objective-C cannot have C array type because C arrays cannot be passed by value, e.g. you cannot write a C function which takes an array as a parameter, or assign one array to another.

You can pass a C array to a function by *address* (or *pointer*), i.e. the passed value is the address of an array and the function can access the original array via that pointer. Care must be taken that the array whose address is passed lives at least as long as the address might be used.

There is a standard trick in C if you need to pass an array by value: in C structure are value types, and structures can have fields of array type, so to pass an array by value you just create a one field structure...

However from your comments you wish your property to have direct access to read and modify the original array, so passing by address is what you need.

To make things simpler, define some types along with the property:

```
@interface BoardModel : NSObject

typedef NSUInteger Board[5][5]; // Give the array a name
typedef Board *BoardPtr;        // A pointer to a Board

@property (readonly) BoardPtr board; // Property return a pointer

@end
```

The definition of the array and property are simply:

```
@implementation BoardModel
{
   Board _board;
}

- (BoardRef) board { return &_board; }
```

Now from elsewhere you can create a `BoardModel` and obtain a pointer to its array:

```
BoardModel *boardModel = [BoardModel new];
BoardPtr theBoard = boardModel.board;
```

and then to access elements of the array you must indirect through `theBoard` and index, e.g.

```
... (*theBoard)[i][j] ...
```

Such an expression directly (and efficiently) access the array.

**Important:** The value stored in `theBoard` is only valid as long as `BoardModel` object referenced by `boardModel` exists - it is a direct pointer into the object. As a pointer to the inside of an object it **does not** work to keep the object alive.

HTH